# function parameters from variables fail as string javascript

Tags: javascript

This Works:

```
setTheme('#222','#000','wheat','red','wheat','none','none');
```

This does not work:=

```
var theme01 = "'#222','#000','wheat','red','wheat','none','none'"; <br>
setTheme(theme01);

console.log(theme01) = '#222','#000','wheat','red','wheat','none','none'
```

So the conversion to string messes it up somehow?

I will be toggling through various themes before capturing the canvas? I had it all working with CSS, but canvas does not capture css changes or css injection. So I now have it all ready to go using Vanilla Javascript, but need help after hours of testing searching just to pass a variable to my function. Grrr. Help!

I have only been at this for a couple of weeks, so it's a learning curve after working only in Wordpress.

```
function setTheme(topp,bott,txt,hlin,vlin,fOrb,sOrb) {  
  var xx = document.querySelectorAll(".hlin");
  for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
    xx[i].style.stroke = hlin;
  }

  var xx = document.querySelectorAll(".vlin");
  for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
    xx[i].style.stroke = vlin;
  }
  var xx = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");
  for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
    xx[i].style.fill = txt;
  } 
  document.getElementById("svg_20").style.fill = topp; 
  document.getElementById("svg_1").style.fill = bott;
  document.getElementById("svg_2").style.fill = bott;
  document.getElementById("svg_3").style.stroke = txt;
  document.getElementById("svg_5").style.stroke = txt;
  document.getElementById("svg_21").style.fill = fOrb;
  document.getElementById("svg_21").style.stroke = sOrb;
```

};

Comment: _So the conversion to string messes it up somehow?_ No, but all of your setTheme's parameters (but the first) are undefined if you pass only a single one... Whatever you are trying to do there is far from sensible

Comment: One string will be a single parameter

Comment: You may want to do `function setTheme(obj) {... document.getElementById("svg_20").style.fill = obj.topp; ....}` and call it as  `setTheme({ topp:'#222',bott:'#000',txt:'wheat',hlin:'red',vlin:'wheat',fOrb'none',sOrb:'none'})` and also you likely want `var xx = document.querySelectorAll("."+hlin);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string will be one parameter for your function. You can use `Function.apply` )1 with a splitted string as second parameter, or even simpler, use the `spread`  operator 2). Demo:

1) [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

2) [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
( () => {
  const log = str => document.querySelector("#result").textContent += `${str} \n`;
  const parameterString = "#222,#000,wheat";
  // no dice
  log("someFn(parameterString) => no dice"); 
  someFn(parameterString);
  
  // use apply
  log("\nsomeFn.apply(null, parameterString.split(\",\")) => ah yes, that works");
  someFn.apply(null, parameterString.split(","));
  
  // or use spread operator
  log("\nsomeFn(...parameterString.split(\",\")) => ah yes, that works too");
  someFn(...parameterString.split(","));
  
  function someFn(p1, p2, p3) {
    log(p1);
    log(p2);
    log(p3);
  }
  
})();
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you, for such a quick response, I will decipher this and learn about Apply, now. At least I know there is a solution. I'm sticking with Javascript to get a foundation, before using jQuery etc.

Comment: @Ryan There is nothing else but javascript in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can’t exchange a list of parameters for a comma-separated string. You should use a data structure to store them, like an array or object. Here’s an example of how it would work with an object.

```
var theme01 = { topp: '#222', bott: '#000', txt: 'wheat' };
function setTheme ( options ) {
    document.getElementById("svg_20").style.fill = options.topp;
    document.getElementById("svg_1").style.fill = options.bott;
    document.getElementById("svg_3").style.fill = options.txt;
}
setTheme( theme01 )
```

Comment: Thank you for Quick response, this is great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an array using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you cannot however pass a string of items and have them be multiple parameters.

```js
function setTheme(topp, bott, txt, hlin, vlin, fOrb, sOrb) {
  console.log(topp)
  console.log(bott)
  console.log(txt)
  console.log(hlin)
  console.log(vlin)
  console.log(fOrb)
  console.log(sOrb)
}

let items = ['#222', '#000', 'wheat', 'red', 'wheat', 'none', 'none']


setTheme(...items)
```